# Not able to get the value of xml attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I am trying to access the value of attribute of xml tag using jquery.
The xml tag attribute that I am trying to access is:

```
<yweather:condition code="30" date="Fri, 04 Mar 2016 12:53 pm AKST" temp="11" text="Partly Cloudy"/>
```

I am trying to access it as follows inside success function:

```
alert($(xml).find('yweather:condition').attr("temp"));
```

But it is alerting "undefined". Not able to understand what went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to escape special characters with `\\` per [jQuery selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Try

```
alert($(xml).find('yweather\\:condition').attr("temp"));
```